# Replace original battery for MacBook Pro "Early 2011" and "Mid-2012"?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, hardware, upgrade

For the following laptops

- [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html)
- [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.9 13" Mid-2012 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html)

Where is possible buy an original battery to each one? I did do a research at [Mac Accessories](https://www.apple.com/shop/mac/accessories)
 but does not appear nothing, it even for new models

Pls indicate your best recommendation Amazon if Apple does not make its own batteries.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not supply (and has never supplied) battery parts to the public for these models.

You may be able to find some third-party replacements on eBay; but you have no way of knowing how good they are (e.g. whether they have followed Apple's manufacturing standards, or whether they use cheaper materials and processes).

Some may even claim to be genuine Apple parts, but they won't be.

Comment: What about [this guy](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/BAP13MBU74V/)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, that's probably a good shout, depending on the OP's location.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Thanks for that - I've *intended* to shop for a new battery for my 2011 17" MBP, and think that guy is OK.